# Invoking a private method, within the object on a UML sequence diagram

Tags: recursion, uml, private, sequence-diagram, staruml

So I have a class diagram here:

[image: Class diagram]

A here's my sequence diagram

[image: Sequence diagram]

I'm invoking a method in object of Newton class and in this method I have to invoke a private method fact() which returns me a factorial of a given number.
This is the body of that newton() method

```
float Newton::newton(int n, int k) {
    return fact(n)/(fact(k) * fact(n-k));
}
```

As you can see fact() is invoked three times. So my question is: do I have to acknowledge (in my sequence diagram) that, fact() is used three times here, and if so - how? Or my sequence diagram is correct?

Comment: currentely only one call of *fact* is visible and this is not right, show the 3 calls of *fact* or show none. To show or not calls of *fact* is your decision, if you think this is usefull to show do, else do not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the **purpose** of the diagram:

- Is it to **document a specific implementation**? In this case, you may show the calls to `fact()`.

  Accuracy is then necessary: the arrow in a sequence diagram is not a dependency (i.e.  "I'll need this function within `newton()`") but a message (i.e. "I'll call this function one time with those arguments").  So, as [Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2458991/bruno) mentioned in the comments, you should then show three distinct calls (i.e. 3 times a call like in your `message 5`).
- Is it to **document your design**? In this case the focus is more on  the interactions between objects. You do not need to show private implementation detail like `fact()` unless the private method would be essential to understand the design. The outside world does not need to know.

In case you're in the first case, note that `fact()` can be implemented recursively or iteratively.  Again an implementation detail.  In both case, [I'd not show what's behind](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/343318/209774) (is it what you tried to do with `message 6`?): in the case of a recursive implementation, it would make the diagram terribly complex for something easily understood in the code, whereas it would bring no additional information for the interaction scenario.